# MySQL delete statement report Truncated incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql

This statement works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE DATE(date_event) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

Using the same WHERE clause in DELETE statement does not works :

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE DATE(date_event) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

Return message :

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2018-01-10T13:22:29.000000Z'
```

Datatype of field "date_event" is CHAR(27).

Testing DATE() function with next SQL statement works fine :

```
SELECT DATE('2018-01-10T13:22:28.000000Z');
```

'2018-01-10'

Here the complete SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_event` char(27) NOT NULL COMMENT 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.ffffffZ',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Test';

INSERT INTO table_name
(date_event) VALUES ('2018-01-10T13:22:28.000000Z');

SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE DATE(date_event) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY);

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE DATE(date_event) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

Comment: Provide a sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) or db-fiddle (https://www.db-fiddle.com/) with example data where you can reproduce the problem

Comment: Try using MySQL `STR_TO_DATE(str,fmt)` function [on the link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)

Comment: "What is the problem?"  it seams you need to convert your date_event column from `CHAR(27)` to the native MySQL datattype `datetime(6)` whats supports `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]` formats which is supported by MySQL 5.6+ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

Comment: Why on earth you have the datatype as CHAR(27) to store dates?

Comment: For historical reasons the CHAR(27) is used. The WHERE clause is valid and DELETE statement could delete the row without making check. Using datetime(6) works fine but many tables must be converted and stored proc edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_event` field is `Char` (string type). We will need to convert it to [MySQL datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) format using [`Str_to_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

`'2018-01-10T13:22:28.000000Z'` can basically be written in terms of format specifiers as: `'%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ'`.

So, your `Delete` query should be as follows (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fHAwBc6NgTEMdorxL3D4fZ/0)**):

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_event, '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ') < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

And, your `Select` query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_event, '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ') < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

**Additional Details:**

- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
- `%m`     Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%T`     Time in 24 hour format (hh:mm:ss)
- `%f`     Microseconds (000000 to 999999)

Complete list of format specifiers can be seen at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format